# how to extract data with regex in python?

Tags: regex

My data has this struture:

```
ID 12354 linea+b 3
ID 15687 linea+b 7
ID 26894 linea+b 10
```

This is my proposition: `r'ID\s+([0-9]+)\s+linea+b\s+([0-9]+)\s+'`
The problem is with `linea+b`  where python does not accept + as a string, it analyzes it as a metacharacter.

Comment: 1. It's not Python, it's the regex engine. 2. You can escape it: `\+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `\` in front of `+` to recognize the symbol, not as an increment

```
r'ID\s+([0-9]+)\s+linea\+b\s+([0-9]+)\s+'
```